# Extracting __AdditionalEmailAttributes

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to export the __AdditionalEmailAttribute1 to 10 for import into our Data Warehouse for analytics and reporting. Is there any way that we can easily extract this data from Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a content builder email you can simply do a get call to the following end point

`{{restEndPoint}}asset/v1/content/assets?$filter=Name%20like%20'New%20EMAIL'`

returned the following in the payload

```
"attributes": [
                        {
                            "displayName": "__AdditionalEmailAttribute1",
                            "name": "__AdditionalEmailAttribute1",
                            "value": "FINDME",
                            "order": 1,
                            "channel": "email",
                            "attributeType": "AdditionalEmailAttribute"
                        },
                        {
                            "displayName": "__AdditionalEmailAttribute2",
                            "name": "__AdditionalEmailAttribute2",
                            "value": "",
                            "order": 2,
                            "channel": "email",
                            "attributeType": "AdditionalEmailAttribute"
                        },
                        {
                            "displayName": "__AdditionalEmailAttribute3",
                            "name": "__AdditionalEmailAttribute3",
                            "value": "",
                            "order": 3,
                            "channel": "email",
                            "attributeType": "AdditionalEmailAttribute"
                        }
```